# PayPal Login button font size

Tags: javascript, html, css, paypal, opencart2.x

I would like to change the PayPal Login button font size, as I noticed it is enough to make the whole button smaller, but it seems that it generates a CSS at the bottom of the head, which will override mines. The button is generated by a script (which I suppose is the one that adds the CSS as well).

```
    <li><span id="pp_login_container" font-size: "14px"></span>
          <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
          <script>paypal.use(['login'], function(login) {
                    login.render ({
                      'appid': '<?php echo $client_id; ?>',
                      'authend': '<?php echo $sandbox; ?>',
                      'scopes': '<?php echo $scopes; ?>',
                      'containerid': 'pp_login_container',
                      'locale': '<?php echo $locale; ?>',
                      'theme': '<?php echo $button_colour; ?>',
                      'returnurl': '<?php echo $return_url; ?>'
                    });
                  });
          </script>
        </span>
    </li>
```

Here is the output:

```
    <span id="pp_login_container">
    <button id="LIwPP85447951" class="LIwPP PPBlue">
      <svg class="PPTM" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="16px" height="17px" viewBox="0 0 16 17">
         <path class="PPTM-btm" fill="#0079c1" d="m15.603 3.917c-0.264-0.505-0.651-0.917-1.155-1.231-0.025-0.016-0.055-0.029-0.081-0.044 0.004 0.007 0.009 0.014 0.013 0.021 0.265 0.506 0.396 1.135 0.396 1.891 0 1.715-0.712 3.097-2.138 4.148-1.425 1.052-3.418 1.574-5.979 1.574h-0.597c-0.45 0-0.9 0.359-1.001 0.798l-0.719 3.106c-0.101 0.438-0.552 0.797-1.002 0.797h-1.404l-0.105 0.457c-0.101 0.438 0.184 0.798 0.633 0.798h2.1c0.45 0 0.9-0.359 1.001-0.798l0.718-3.106c0.101-0.438 0.551-0.797 1.002-0.797h0.597c2.562 0 4.554-0.522 5.979-1.574 1.426-1.052 2.139-2.434 2.139-4.149 0-0.755-0.132-1.385-0.397-1.891z"></path>
         <path class="PPTM-top" fill="#00457c" d="m9.27 6.283c-0.63 0.46-1.511 0.691-2.641 0.691h-0.521c-0.45 0-0.736-0.359-0.635-0.797l0.628-2.72c0.101-0.438 0.552-0.797 1.002-0.797h0.686c0.802 0 1.408 0.136 1.814 0.409 0.409 0.268 0.611 0.683 0.611 1.244 0 0.852-0.315 1.507-0.944 1.97zm3.369-5.42c-0.913-0.566-2.16-0.863-4.288-0.863h-4.372c-0.449 0-0.9 0.359-1.001 0.797l-2.957 12.813c-0.101 0.439 0.185 0.798 0.634 0.798h2.099c0.45 0 0.901-0.358 1.003-0.797l0.717-3.105c0.101-0.438 0.552-0.797 1.001-0.797h0.598c2.562 0 4.554-0.524 5.979-1.575 1.427-1.051 2.139-2.433 2.139-4.148-0.001-1.365-0.439-2.425-1.552-3.123z"></path>
      </svg>
      <b>Log In with PayPal</b>
    </button>
    </span>
```

And the CSS that changes is something like (positioned at the end of head in the HTML):

```
<style type="text/css">/*!reset via github.com/premasagar/cleanslate*/
....
.LIwPP {
...
  font-size: 16px !important;
...
```

[Here is the CSS that is using](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate)

I trying to do this in OpenCart2 into the header.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a simple and elegant solution by just adding:

```
<style scoped> .LIwPP { font-size: 13px !important;} </style>
```

The final solution:

```
        <li><span id="pp_login_container"></span>
          <style scoped> .LIwPP { font-size: 13px !important;} </style>
          <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js"></script>
          <script>paypal.use(['login'], function(login) {
                    login.render ({
                      'appid': '<?php echo $client_id; ?>',
                      'authend': '<?php echo $sandbox; ?>',
                      'scopes': '<?php echo $scopes; ?>',
                      'containerid': 'pp_login_container',
                      'locale': '<?php echo $locale; ?>',
                      'theme': '<?php echo $button_colour; ?>',
                      'returnurl': '<?php echo $return_url; ?>'
                    });
                  });
          </script>
        </span>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are asking, but you could try changing the actual width and height of the button while changing the font size:

```
   .button-small-text {
       height: 30px;
       width: 75px;
       font-size: 10px;
   }
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but I actually managed to fix it by adding this script to the header.tpl:

```
      <script>
      $(window).bind("load", function() {
        // code here
        var css = '.LIwPP { font-size: 14px !important;}'
            head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
            style = document.createElement('style');

        style.type = 'text/css';
        if (style.styleSheet){
          style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
          style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }

        head.appendChild(style);
      });
    </script>
```